# Is there a better way to do this than using a query string in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, query-string

I have two models, we'll call them Entry and Comments for our example, that are associated as Entry `has_many :comments` and Comment `belongs_to` Entry. When a new comment is created, I need to obviously supply the id of the Entry for the foreign key. Right now, I'm using a query string. It works like this. A user views and entry, clicks a link to create a new comment (the link looks something like b/new?a_id=1) and then I use the build method to create the new record.

I know if I nested the resources it'd work just fine, but there are reasons that I don't want to do that, namely that I plan to nest a resource under Comments and don't want to go so many levels deep.

I initially had the form for a new comment on the Entry show page, but was having problems doing some custom validations and passing the error messages, etc. (namely, I needed to count the words before submitting).

Any thoughts? I'm not opposed to using query strings, just not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly can't see the problem with nested resources. You're going to have to identify the Entry in your case so your choices are `POST /entries/123/comments` or `POST /comments?entry_id=123`. Personally I prefer the former.

Comment: I just don't like to nest more than one-level deep. Later on, I'll need something like entries/123/comments/2/votes/23/ or something like that (these are just examples, my app isn't about entries and comments and maybe aren't the best example, because comments need to be associated --- but in terms of user experience should and can be separated from their entries). So I know it *would* work, but I'd really prefer to deal with just comments/2/votes/23 later on and not nest so deeply.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe `shallow => true` is the way to go?

Comment: That's not going to help you in this case (creating a Comment attached to an Entry). It will allow you to show comments with `/comments/123` though, without needing to identify the Entry.

Comment: well --- I can just build a form and new object through the nested route, (entry/123/comment/new) but still have routes where I can access the comment (comment/1), right?

Comment: Yes, only those routes where there's an existing sub-record are shallow, otherwise you get the fully scoped ones.